# Create React App not creating Bundle.js on npm run build

Tags: javascript, webpack, create-react-app, bundle, github-pages

I have a project built through Create React App and I am following [this tutorial](https://github.com/rafgraph/spa-github-pages) to deploy it to GitHub Pages. The deploy itself is almost working, as whatever I write above the `<script>` in index.html is deployed to the correct URL, but I can't figure out what I should be loading. In the tutorial, they link `build/bundle.js`, but when I run `npm run build`, no bundle file is created. I *think* that I just need to link to my bundled app and that will fix my problem, but I don't know where to find it. I haven't reconfigured babel or webpack from the out-of-the-box create-react-app.
My index.HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Start Single Page Apps for GitHub Pages -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Single Page Apps for GitHub Pages
      // MIT License
      // https://github.com/rafgraph/spa-github-pages
      // This script checks to see if a redirect is present in the query string,
      // converts it back into the correct url and adds it to the
      // browser's history using window.history.replaceState(...),
      // which won't cause the browser to attempt to load the new url.
      // When the single page app is loaded further down in this file,
      // the correct url will be waiting in the browser's history for
      // the single page app to route accordingly.
      (function(l) {
        if (l.search[1] === '/' ) {
          var decoded = l.search.slice(1).split('&').map(function(s) { 
            return s.replace(/~and~/g, '&')
          }).join('?');
          window.history.replaceState(null, null,
              l.pathname.slice(0, -1) + decoded + l.hash
          );
        }
      }(window.location))
    </script>
    <!-- End Single Page Apps for GitHub Pages -->

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!-- single page app in bundle.js -->
    <p>Testing</p>
    <script src="/build/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest following the [official guide](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages)